# jQuery: Binding events (mouseenter, mouseleave, click) doesn't trigger for different event types

Tags: jquery

The following code doesn't trigger the right events for the different event types and actions but if I split the function "on" into 3 on function, without binding them together, they work without any problems. Maybe I'm just a little bit blind, because I'm a little tired but I would really appreciate it, if you guys could help me out.

Doesn't trigger correctly, instead, it triggers just the mouseenter event:

```
var $elemTemp = $(elem);
var matrix = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
};
var matrixOld = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
};

$elemTemp.on("mouseenter mouseleave click", "li", function(event) {
    if (event.type = "mouseenter") {
        matrix.x = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]);
        matrix.y = parseInt($(this).parent("ul").attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]);
        console.log("x:" + matrix.x + ", y:" + matrix.y);
    } else if (event.type = "mouseleave") {
        console.log("test");
        matrixOld.x = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]);
        matrixOld.y = parseInt($(this).parent("ul").attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]);
        console.log("x_:" + matrixOld.x + ", y_:" + matrixOld.y);
    } else if (event.type = "click") {
        return {
            "x": parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]),
            "y": parseInt($(this).parent("ul").attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0])
        };
    }
});
```

Does trigger correctly for different event types:

```
var $elemTemp = $(elem);
var matrix = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
};
var matrixOld = {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
};

$elemTemp.on("mouseenter", "li", function(event) {
    matrix.x = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]);
    matrix.y = parseInt($(this).parent("ul").attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]);
    console.log("x:" + matrix.x + ", y:" + matrix.y);
});

$elemTemp.on("mouseleave", "li", function(event) {
        matrixOld.x = parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]);
        matrixOld.y = parseInt($(this).parent("ul").attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]);
        console.log("x_:" + matrixOld.x + ", y_:" + matrixOld.y);
});

$elemTemp.on("click", "li", function(event) {
    return {
        "x": parseInt($(this).attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0]),
        "y": parseInt($(this).parent("ul").attr("class").match(/(\d)/)[0])
    };
});
```

DOM-Structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="row-1">
        <li class="col-1"></li>
        <li class="col-2"></li>
        <li class="col-3"></li>
        <li class="col-4"></li>
        <li class="col-5"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the value not checking it, change

```
if (event.type = "mouseenter") { ...
```

to

```
if (event.type == "mouseenter") { ...
```

and do the same for the rest of them.

One equalsign sets the value, two checks the value, three checks the value strict.

Comment: Sometimes if you code too much you can't see these little things... I should've just went outside for 5 minutes... Thank you so much though, that was the (obvious) problem.

Comment: @OkanEsen - we've all been there, just happy to help!